# How to create superuser in custom user model in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a superuser in the custom user model in Django. But after applying migrations no file creates in migration folder but it shows that migration is applied. after that when I try to make a superuser it gives an error as no-table found. here is my code that I have used to create custom user model in Django:

```
from django.db import models

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager


class SignUpManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, age, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("insert user")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("insert username")
        if not name:
            raise ValueError("insert name")
        if not age:
            raise ValueError("insert age")
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            age=age,
            name=name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, age, name, password):

        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
            age=age,
            name=name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserSignupModel(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="date joined", auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="last login", auto_now=True)

    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email", "name", "age",]
    objects = SignUpManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in settings file. For more information, please follow [substituting-a-custom-user-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)
As you can see on documentation, you should add new app to `INSTALLED_APPS` also.